# Windows 7 Refuses To Install To A Partition

Tags: windows-7, installation

I have 4 HDDs in my PC on a Gigabyte EP45-UD3 rev1.0 motherboard on SATA ports 0-3 and running AHCI mode.

Windows 7 refuses to let me install to any partitions or disks I select saying `Setup was unable to create a new system partition or locate an existing system partition.`

I will get to the bottom of this, after I sacrifice my Friday nights and weekends to Microsoft (they don't just want my money, they want my soul).

Keep tuned, if no one has the answer, I will find one. I suspect I have to rip out 3 HDDs so that the n00bs at Microsoft can actually deal with spinning media.

Really angers me how paid-for-products are so inferior to Linux they don't even qualify to be called "software".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, ensure that ***all*** other external disk drives are disconnected.  This includes USB sticks, card readers, USB hard drives, the works.  This worked for lots of people with the same problem [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproinstall/thread/8c2c1ac9-dc18-40af-a2b1-88dfaf9c2e70).

Download the **SATA RAID** drivers from [**Gigabyte's website**](http://www.gigabyte.com.tw/Support/Motherboard/Driver_Model.aspx?ProductID=2920#anchor_os) and stick the drivers from **`GSATA\Floppy32`** onto a floppy disk (see below) :-)

[image]

Bung it in your floppy drive and use <kbd>F6</kbd> during Windows 7 when prompted to supply the correct SATA RAID drivers.  This may allow the setup program to properly communicate with the disks.

Failing the above, switch from **`AHCI`** to **`ATA`** in the BIOS and try it again, if possible.  If you need to know how to do this, refer to the manual [**here**](http://www.gigabyte.com.tw/Support/Motherboard/Manual_DownloadFile.aspx?FileType=Manual&FileID=18782).

Comment: I removed my other 3 HDDs, and the installation worked just fine.